# I am trying to tell Finder to move files with AppleScript. But I don't know how to deal with duplication/replacement/skipping

Tags: macos, applescript, move, finder, file-management

The script is as below:

```
tell application "Finder"

    set destinFolder to (choose folder)

    try
        move selection to destinFolder
    on error vMessage number -15267
        display dialog "" & vMessage
    end try

end tell
```

Basically,if a file with the same name has already existed in the destination folder, I want users have the choice to duplicate,replace or just skip that file and continue the next file movement **using AppleScript**. Just like the pic below.

[image]

**Update:** I know how to display a dialog like the one above,the problem is I don't know how to implement the "duplicate,replace or just skip" logic in AppleScript. And besides, I want to keep this line:

```
move selection to destinFolder
```

Because this line of code show a proper moving progress percentage in a single dialog, using `repeat` will lose that benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
set destinFolder to (choose folder)
set destItems to every paragraph of (do shell script "ls " & quoted form of (POSIX path of destinFolder))

tell application "Finder"
    set mySelection to selection
    repeat with anItem in mySelection
        set itemName to anItem's name
        if itemName is in destItems then
            display alert "An item named " & itemName & " already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it with the one you're moving?" buttons {"Skip", "Replace"} default button "Replace"
            if button returned of the result = "Replace" then move anItem to destinFolder with replacing
        else
            try
                move anItem to destinFolder
            end try
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

or this:

```
    set destinFolder to (choose folder)

tell application "Finder"
    set mySelection to selection
    repeat with anItem in mySelection

        try
            move anItem to destinFolder
        on error errMsg number errNum
            if errNum = -15267 then
                display alert "An item named " & itemName & " already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it with the one you're moving?" buttons {"Skip", "Replace"} default button "Replace"
                if button returned of the result = "Replace" then move anItem to destinFolder with replacing
            else
                tell me
                    activate
                    display alert errMsg & return & return & "Error number" & errNum buttons "Cancel"
                end tell
            end if
        end try

    end repeat
end tell
```

EDIT
This script will not give you a choice for each item that exists in the destination folder

```
set destinFolder to (choose folder)

tell application "Finder"
    set mySelection to selection
    try
        move mySelection to destinFolder
    on error errMsg number errNum
        if errNum = -15267 then
            display alert "One or more items already exist in this location. Do you want to replace them with the ones you're moving?" buttons {"Skip", "Replace"} default button "Replace"
            if button returned of the result = "Replace" then move mySelection to destinFolder with replacing
        else
            tell me
                activate
                display alert errMsg & return & return & "Error number" & errNum buttons "Cancel"
            end tell
        end if
    end try

end tell
```

Comment: I know how to display a dialog like the one above,the problem is I don't know how to implement the "duplicate,replace or just skip" logic in AppleScript.

Comment: Replace and skip logic is in my answer.

Comment: Oh,I didn't notice that at first glance,sorry.Besides,is there any way to keep using 'move selection to destinFolder' instead of using 'repeat'? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its not posible to display finder copy UI using applescript. You should implement your own UI.
your script will display this.
[image]

Take a look at [Mac Finder native copy dialog](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=28628) article.